# How to do continuous deployment - c++ on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment

I have a source on a repository server. The application is running on an AWS instance. I could make a script that logs, makes the pull, compiles, and copies the new binary to it's destination.

But how do I copy the new binary if the application is running? what's the usual way to do this? Do I have to stop the application to make an update? how does continuous deployment works then?

I'm using linux, the application is in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to restart the application after copying the binary. I would highly recommend that you use one of the frameworks for continuous building/integration to make this less painful though, for example [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

It will not only help with the actual deployment process, but can also run tests for you and only deploy if the tests succeed. There is also a plugin for AWS integration.